# Convert list generated from mapply to matrix or data frame

Tags: r

I have an `R` function called `sims` that has multiple parameters that can take on a range of values (i.e. two parameters are probabilities, `p1` and `p2` that could range from 0 to 1; to others are negative binomial distribution parameters `mu` and `size` that can take on any positive value). I will need to look at hundreds of permutations though, so  I am using `mapply` to run a range of values. My question is regarding properly structuring the output from `mapply`.

For simplicity of this question, say I am looking at a number of ranges for `p1` and `p2`. Unfortunately the actual function is several hundred lines long, so I will provide both the function command line and code that recreates the result. I am providing the function line code in case there is a solution (particularly in the `mapply` command) that may solve this problem. My approaches have been to restructure after the data are returned.

When I run the function with a single set of parameters, it returns a data frame that is properly structured for my analysis. It has 11 columns for the various outputs (3 models for estimated `mu`, 3 models for `size`, 4 columns to specify the true parameters and probabilities, and the last column specifies a "type", either 1 or 2. It has 6 rows, which is always 2x the `num_sims` parameter in the function since there are 2 types that look at each model.

For instance, when I run:

```
single.result<-sims(num_sims=3,num_chains=2000,true_r0=0.9,true_k=0.25,p1=0.3,p2=0.6)
```

it returns a an 11 columns and 6 rows in a date frame that looks like this:

```
r1<-c(0.9107957, 0.8887721, 0.9099391, 0.9009913, 0.8887699, 0.8989657) #parameter results for mu options, model 1
r2<-c(0.9372350, 0.9100609, 0.9457752, 0.9214452, 0.9200479, 0.9235448)#parameter results for mu options, model 2
r3<-c(0.9372350, 0.9100609, 0.9457752, 0.9214452, 0.9200479, 0.9235448)#parameter results for mu options model 3
r4<-c(0.2545718, 0.2496371, 0.2525968, 0.2526767, 0.2485226, 0.2376562)#parameter results for size options model 1
r5<-c(0.2594364, 0.2542357, 0.2595367, 0.2618499, 0.2630876, 0.2401987)#parameter results for size options model 2
r6<-c(0.2594364, 0.2542357, 0.2595367, 0.2618499, 0.2630876, 0.2401987)#parameter results for size options model 3
r7<-rep(0.9,6);r8<-rep(0.25,6); #true mu and size 
r9<-rep(0.3,6); r10<-rep(0.6,6) #probability values
r11<-c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3)) #"type" - either type 1 or 2 (runs num_sims for each type)
single.result.data<-data.frame(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11)
names(single.result.data)<-NULL
```

But when I run it in `mapply` over, for example, 4 combinations of `p1` and `p2`:

```
p1<-c(0.25,0.50,0.75,1.00) #example of applying 4 combinations of p1 and p2
p2<-c(rep(0.3,2),rep(0.6,2))
mapply.result<-mapply(sims,p1=p1, p2=p2, num_sims=3,num_chains=2000,true_k=0.25,true_r0=0.9)
```

The `mapply.result` is a list of 44 vectors (11 variables x 4 combinations of `p1` and `p2`). An example of how it looks is:

```
mapply.result.data<-unlist(c(list(c(single.result.data[-c(9:10)],list(rep(0.25,6)),list(rep(0.3,6)))),
                           list(c(single.result.data[-c(9:10)],list(rep(0.50,6)),list(rep(0.3,6)))),
                           list(c(single.result.data[-c(9:10)],list(rep(0.75,6)),list(rep(0.6,6)))),
                           list(c(single.result.data[-c(9:10)],list(rep(1.0,6)),list(rep(0.6,6))))),recursive=FALSE)
```

My desired output would be an extension of what the single set of parameters looks like, but each new combination of p values would be added on the end. In other words, it would be structured like this:

```
rep1<-single.result.data; rep1[9]<-0.25; rep1[10]<-0.3
rep2<-single.result.data; rep2[9]<-0.50; rep2[10]<-0.3
rep3<-single.result.data; rep3[9]<-0.75; rep3[10]<-0.6
rep4<-single.result.data; rep4[9]<-1.00; rep4[10]<-0.6
desired.data<-rbind(data.frame(rep1),data.frame(rep2),data.frame(rep3),data.frame(rep4))
```

I do not know how to restructure the list data outputted from `mapply` to be suitable for analysis like where I run a single set of parameters. I have of course exhaustively searched Stack Overflow and the internet. Based on this, these are the approaches I have tried so far, none of which work:

```
test1<-matrix(unlist(mapply.result.data), ncol=11, byrow = TRUE) #24x11 matrix, but values arent correct
test2<-matrix(unlist(mapply.result.data), ncol=11,byrow = FALSE)#24x11 matrix, but values arent correct
test3<-matrix(mapply.result.data, ncol=11, byrow = TRUE) #doesnt work,list of 44
test4<-matrix(mapply.result.data, ncol=11,byrow = FALSE)#doesnt work, list of 44
test5<-data.frame(mapply.result.data)#6 obs of 44 variables
test6<-data.frame(t(mapply.result.data)) #1 obs of 44 variables
test7<-data.frame(matrix(unlist(mapply.result.data), ncol=length(mapply.result.data), byrow=T)) #6 obs of 44 variables
test8<-do.call(rbind.data.frame, mapply.result.data) #44 obs of 6 variables
library (plyr)
test9<-ldply (rbind.data.frame, mapply.result.data) #returns error: Error in fs[[i]](x, ...) : attempt to apply non-function
test10<-data.frame(t(sapply(mapply.result.data,c))) #44 obs of 6 variable
```

Any advice - on either restructuring the data or taking a different approach than `mapply` - would be much appreciated!

Comment: `do.call(rbind.data.frame, mapply(..., SIMPLIFY=FALSE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I followed your example right, but I gave it a go. I have written my own `sims()` which returns the dataframe of which dimension you have described. I think the main trick you are looking for is `Map()` here.

```
library("tidyr")

sims <- function(num_sims, mu0, n0, p1, p2){

  out <- data.frame(
    replicate(6, runif(num_sims)),
    rep(mu0, num_sims),
    rep(n0, num_sims),
    rep(p1, num_sims), 
    rep(p2, num_sims), 
    c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3))
  )

  names(out) <- c("mu1", "mu2", "mu3", "n1", "n2", "n3", "mu0", "n0", "p1", "p2", "type")
  return(out)
}

p1 <- c(0.25,0.50,0.75,1.00) 
p2 <- c(rep(0.3,2),rep(0.6,2))

Map(sims, p1=p1, p2=p2, num_sims=6, mu0=0.9, n0=0.9) %>% do.call(rbind, .) %>% data.frame()
```

Thanks to the comment, the last line can also be better written as follows,

```
Map(sims, p1=p1, p2=p2, num_sims=6, mu0=0.9, n0=0.9) %>% do.call(rbind.data.frame, .)
Map(sims, p1=p1, p2=p2, num_sims=6, mu0=0.9, n0=0.9) %>% dplyr::bind_rows()
```

Comment: (1) You can replace `do.call(rbind, .) %>% data.frame()` with `do.call(rbind.data.frame, .)`. (2) Since you're suggesting a `tidyverse` package, you might also include `dplyr` so that you can more replace that with the more-robust `%>% dplyr::bind_rows(.)`.